flutter app not launching after ading google maps
after adding google maps to my flutter app i haven't being able to launch on my virtual device my mobile phone
Launching lib\main.dart on M2006C3MG in debug mode...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install C:\Users\HP\Desktop\eShop_app\eshop_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED: Invalid apk]
Error launching application on M2006C3MG.
I tried changing the usb cord it did not work. I want the app to launch in debug mode on my virtual device so i can continue to code

i guess it's just the permission issue on your device like you didn't allow the apk to install

Could you show us your code? It seems like you likely added Google Maps incorrectly which causes an error while compiling which results in your invalid APK.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
